# SceneKit how to add a texture inner SCNSphere

Tags: textures, scenekit

i know how to add a texture on SCNSphere surface,but when i move camera into sphere is dark,so i want to know how to add a texture to the inner surface,here is what i use now:

```
let boingBall = SCNSphere(radius: 4.0)
        let boingBallNode = SCNNode(geometry: boingBall)
        boingBallNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 3, z: -10)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boingBallNode)

        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "texture.png")
        material.specular.contents = UIColor.whiteColor()
        material.shininess = 1.0
        boingBall.materials = [ material ]
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there any lighting on the inside of the surface? Is the material double sided?

Comment: and by double-sided he means that the `doubleSided` property of your material is `YES` (default is `NO`)

Comment: @mnuages yes,you are right!

Answer (score -1):

first lets create camera and lights

```
func camAndLights(){
    let cameranode = SCNNode()
    cameranode.camera = SCNCamera()

    cameranode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 70, z: 200)
    cameranode.camera?.zFar = 1000.0



    let lightbrnl = SCNNode()
    lightbrnl.light = SCNLight()
    lightbrnl.light?.type = SCNLight.LightType.directional
    lightbrnl.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 200, z: 0)
    lightbrnl.light?.zFar = 1000.0
    lightbrnl.light?.color = UIColor.cyan

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightbrnl)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameranode)
```

note the camera and light position.z cus we will make the radius of our "world" sphere bigger.
then lets create a function called "world" to create our sphere.
set the sphere's first material to 
`isdouble = true`
and centre the world node in the middle at (0,0,0)

```
   func world(){
    let world = SCNSphere(radius: 700)

    world.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "sky")

    world.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
    let worldnode = SCNNode(geometry: world)

    worldnode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(worldnode)

}
```

and that should do it. just call `camAndLights()` and `world()` in your did load func.
enjoy!